# Comparing two columns and their values and outputting the greater value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to compare two columns ("Shows") from different tables and showing which one has the greater number ("Rating") associated with it in another table.

[image]

Ignore the operation column above as part of the solution that I'm trying to get, it's just to illustrate for you what I'm trying to compare.

**Important note**: If the names are duplicated. Compare the matching pair in their corresponding order. (1st with 1st, 2nd with 2nd, 3rd with 3rd etc..) illustrated in the table below:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following in cell `F3` for an array solution that spills the entire result at once:

```
=LET(sA, A3:A6, rA, B3:B6, sB, C3:C6, rB, D3:D6, CNTS, LAMBDA(x, 
 LET(seq, SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)), MAP(seq, LAMBDA(s,ROWS(FILTER(x,(x=INDEX(x,s))
  *(seq<=s))))))), cntsA, CNTS(sA), cntsB, CNTS(sB), eval, MAP(sA, rA, cntsA, 
  LAMBDA(s,r,c,IF(r > FILTER(rB, (sB=s) * (cntsB=c)), "Table 1", "Table 2"))), 
HSTACK(sA, eval))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

### Explanation

The main idea is to count repeated show values. We use a user `LAMBDA` function `CNTS`, to avoid repetition of the same formula twice. Once we have the counts (`cntsA`, `contsB`), we use `MAP` to iterate over **Table 1** elements with the counts and look for specific show and counts to compare with `Table 2` columns. The `FILTER` function will return always a single value (based on sample data). Finally, we prepare the output as expected using `HSTACK`.

Comment: Hi David, just one more thing. If it has the same Rating numer (Ex: Family Guy's Rating is equal in Table1 and Table2). Is it possible to display the text 'SAME'?

Comment: You can use the following formula to return `SAME` in this case: `=LET(sA, A3:A6, rA, B3:B6, sB, C3:C6, rB, D3:D6, CNTS, LAMBDA(x, LET(seq, SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)), MAP(seq, LAMBDA(s,ROWS(FILTER(x,(x=INDEX(x,s)) * (seq<=s))))))), cntsA, CNTS(sA), cntsB, CNTS(sB), eval, MAP(sA, rA, cntsA, LAMBDA(s,r,c, LET(f, FILTER(rB, (sB=s) * (cntsB=c)), IF(r=f, "SAME", IF(r > f, "Table 1", "Table 2"))))), HSTACK(sA, eval))`

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
=IF(INDEX(FILTER($B$3:$B$6,$A$3:$A$6=G3),COUNTIFS($G$3:$G3,G3))>INDEX(FILTER($E$3:$E$6,$D$3:$D$6=G3),COUNTIFS($G$3:$G3,G3)),"Table-1","Table-2")
```

[image]

Comment: I thought about a `COUNTIFS` solution too, but I prefer to generate array solutions, so I don't need to deal with expanding the formula down. This is a great solution also under this scenario.

Comment: @DavidLeal This can be converted to spill down array formula I believe.